# Inserting a row into a sql table in c# with autoincrement primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do I execute a table insert command when the ID column is the primary key and set to autoincrement?

I've tried the following:

```
      using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            SqlCommand identChange = conn.CreateCommand();
            identChange.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON";
            conn.Open();
            string commtext = @"Insert INTO table1 (ID, Username)
                       SELECT @ID, @User";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(commtext, conn);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", -1);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", loggedinuser);
            identChange.ExecuteNonQuery();
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

but regardless of what value is put into ID (i've tried 0 and -1), it creates a new row with that value under the ID column. As a result, when I try to insert the next row, it gives me an error since now I have two rows with the same ID.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of an auto-incrementing key that you don't *have* to pass in a value for it?

Comment: Why are you setting `IDENTITY_INSERT`?

Comment: I read somewhere that you should set ID to 0 for it to autoincrement. But you're right, it works if you just ignore it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just don't have to mention the column if it is a autoincrement column.

```
string commtext = @"Insert INTO table1 (Username) SELECT @User";
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(commtext, conn);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", loggedinuser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You say something like this:

```
int addUser( string userName )
{
  if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) throw new ArgumentException("invalid user name" , "userName") ;
  int user_id ;
  string connectString = GetSomeConnectString() ;

  using ( SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( connectString ) )
  using ( SqlCommand    cmd        = connection.CreateCommand() )
  {

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text ;
    cmd.CommandText = @"
insert dbo.user ( user_name ) values ( @user_Name )
select user_id = @@SCOPE_IDENTITY
" ;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@user_name" , userName ) ;

    connection.Open() ;
    user_id = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar() ;
    connection.Close() ;
  }

  return user_id ;
}
```

any column with an `identity` property (or autoincrementing column) can't be specified on the insert. You have to specify the columns whose value you are supplying. Any columns not supplied must be nullable, have a default constraint or be an auto-incrementing column.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to explicitly set the ID you don't set IDENTITY_INSERT ON otherwise use the auto incremented value.

```
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
    {           
        conn.Open();
        string commtext = @"Insert INTO table1 (Username)
                   SELECT @User";
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(commtext, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", loggedinuser);
        identChange.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```